# How to find out why a website is performing badly on Android phones?

Tags: user-research, research, analytics

We have an ecommerce website that constantly performs worse in Android web browsers. Click-through rate, conversion, are all significantly lower than iOS device browsers.

How would one start to check why this is happening? No more insights can be given by analytics. So it is up to user research to define what the problem is.

Any ideas are welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In an ideal situation there should be some clue that you might be able to pick up from the analytics, although they may not be significant enough to give you a solid starting point.

If you had access to a large number enough of Android and iOS users, then the first thing might be some basic usability testing to get an understanding of the different user attitudes, expectations and behaviour.

Ultimately it might just be that the e-commerce site's design or products/services are more appealing to iOS users. It would also be interesting to see a comparison between Android users that rate the website higher than those that rate it lower, as well as compare the range of usability and customer satisfaction scores between Android and iOS users.

That's probably as much as can be said without looking at the actual analytics but hopefully there are a couple of starting points to do further research.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen several studies that show that iPhone users spend more money than android-users. Probably because if they can afford an iPhone which is usually more expensive than an average android phone they have more money to spend in general.

The same has been true for Mac and Windows computers.

I have no idea of course if this applies on your site but perhaps that could be an interesting hypothesis to test?

Here's one study:

https://www.wolfgangdigital.com/blog/battle-of-the-internet-giants-apple-vs-facebook-june-2021/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting with comparing the Google Analytics between the Android and iOS version of your ecommerce website. Seeing what the similarities and differences are between the two will give you some clues about the users behaviors. For example, on what pages are your users dropping off? How far in the check out do they get before they abandon cart OR do they click the CTA buttons or not? Using these insight, your business goals, and the most common user needs your user comes to your website for you can then conduct user interviews and usability testing for the android version.

If you can reach your actual users - say through an email sign up you can ask them both about their direct experience and to conduct usability testing by completing common tasks. Then you can define the problem. Some questions that may be popping up are - Is it that Android users are less likely to buy or is there a bug preventing users from accessing the products/services or something else. By empathizing and then defining the problem, you can address the problem at it's root and then get back to making conversions!